# What is the difference between closing [close(3)] and clearing [fd_clr(3)] a file descriptor?

Tags: c, linux, file, file-descriptor

I am having problems with an automated software testing, which is blaming use of freed resource when I use fd_clr(3) after using close(3) in a fd. Is there something wrong with doing this?

```
for(i = 0; i < nfds; ++i) {
    if (FD_ISSET(i, &myFdSet)) {
        close(i);
        FD_CLR(i, &myFdSet);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I agree. A lot of these questions are asked because people don't do the proper research beforehand.

Comment: If people completely understood everything they read, stackoverflow would not exist.

Comment: Then please try to write what's bothering you about what you have read in your question. What specifically are you wondering about? What are your doubts? Your thoughts? And please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FD_CLR()` only changes a local `fd_set`, which is a C data structure to store info about a list of file descriptors.

`close()` is a system call that closes the file descriptor.

The `fd_set` is used in the `select()` system call. With `select()` you get information about the state of the list of file descriptors that are stored in your `fd_set` struct.

The reason why you see the `FD_CLR()` just below the `close()`, is that there's no longer need/purpose in asking the state if the closed file descriptor.

Comment: *there's no longer need/purpose in asking the state if the closed file descriptor.*  There's not only no need to ask the state, calling `select()` on a closed file descriptor is also is wrong as the file descriptor could be reused by another thread for a completely unrelated file.

Answer (score 1):

So, FD_ISSET and FD_CLR are part of the pselect API, read more in the man page here http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/FD_CLR.3.html

It is basically managing a list of all the file numbers you want to wait on, in your next call to pselect, so clearing a file that you have closed makes sense.

Your code is asking, for all the files I was listening for, close the file and remove from the set.

close() actually closes the file. You should not call close multiple times on the same file, or you will see this error. Perhaps some other code is also closing the file?

Comment: I'll check if close gets called for the same file in other code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the software is really flagging such use of `FD_CLR`, the automated software is broken. You are **removing** the closed file descriptor from the watched set, and `FD_CLR` is precisely the way to do that.

As a work-around, you could transpose the `close()` and `FD_CLR` which won't change the meaning of the code, but will appease the buggy analysis tool.